# Bash время выполнение скрипта в милисекундах

Tags: bash, таймер

Есть обычный тестовый скрипт, который копирует содержимое папки и показывает в конце время выполнения операции. Но это время указывается в секундах, а реальный скрипт может выполняться гораздо быстрее и обычно мне возвращается 0 секунд, хотя он то может быть выполнен за 0,5 сек или  0,005 сек.

Вопрос: Есть ли возможность подсчёта времени в милисекундах?

```
#!/bin/bash
START=$(date +%s)

# начало скрипта
cp -r /home/it/Downloads /home/it/Downloads/bash-time
# конец скрипта

END=$(date +%s)
DIFF=$(( $END - $START ))
echo "It took $DIFF seconds"
```

Comment: Возможно Вам нужна утилита `time`? `man time`

Comment: bash имеют встроенную команду time в случае если нужен настраиваемый вывод, то следует обращаться напрямую /usr/bin/time, к примеру команда  `/usr/bin/time -f %E sleep 0.03` вернет фактически затраченное время на выполнение команды `sleep 0.03`.

Answer (score 3):

Используя ваш код немного модифицируем и получим следующее:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
START=$(date +%s%N)

# начало скрипта
cp -r /home/it/Downloads /home/it/Downloads/bash-time
# конец скрипта

END=$(date +%s%N)
DIFF=$(($($END - $START)/1000000))
echo "It took $DIFF milliseconds"
```

Аргумент `%N` вернет наносекунды, 1 миллисекунда равна 1000000 наносекундам.

**UPD:** Не проверял, но должно работать.

Comment: `DIFF=$(($($END - $START)/1000000))` лишний знак доллара у вас в команде: `DIFF=$((($END - $START)/1000000))`

Comment: Спасибо, пишет: "It took 37206 miliseconds" супер - это значит 37 секунд и 206 милисекунд!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте утилиту `time`:

```sh
$ time sleep 0.123
```

```
real    0m0,125s
user    0m0,001s
sys     0m0,001s
```

Answer (score 1):

Для вывода минут секунд и тысячных секунды можно использовать следующую конструкцию скрипта:

```
#!/bin/bash
TIMEFORMAT="время выполнения %lR"
time {
    cp -r /home/it/Downloads /home/it/Downloads/bash-time
    #Набор команд, возможно использование функций
    #и конструкций проверки типа [ $a ] && { echo 1; exit 0; }
}
#конец скрипта либо exit
```

Вывод:
`время выполнения 1m2.004s`

Таймер возвращает общее время выполнения перечисленных команд между родительскими { }, возможно так же вызвать несколько `time {...}` в одном скрипте и переобъявить переменную TIMEFORMAT для каждого.

---

Более подробно о формате вывода времени команды `time` можно почитать тут
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html

UPD: если вы изменили переменную TIMEFORMAT в терминале и хотите вернуть ее в текущей сессии по умолчанию, то выполните команду `unset TIMEFORMAT`.

Comment: Например при выполнении следующего скрипта, сначала отображается время, а потом сам скрипт: #!/bin/bash
TIMEFORMAT="время выполнения %lR"
time {
i=0;
for i in {1..101};
do curl -H "Authorization: Bearer mytoken" -s -w "$i: time: %{time_total}\n\n" https://mysite.com/userapi/installationList & i=$(($i+1));
done
}

Comment: @Igor-Potapov и открывающаяся фигурная скобка должна быть на одной строке с time

Comment: возможно так же за счет того, что часть команд отрабатывает после запуска скрипта так как они отвязываются от текущей сессии, общее время от этого выводится ближе к началу, тут любой таймер так сработает. Если убрать поток stdout у curl или записывать его в файл, то общее время выполнения скрипта вы увидите в конце.